# sprockets version number automatically increment rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

Sprockets has a configurable version number.  Is there a good way to have it automatically incremented on every compile? Or every deploy?

```
# application.rb
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: Probably not, since that's not the point of the version number. Assets that change will automatically have their fingerprint altered, busting and caching that may be taking place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to bump this number unless you explicitly want to alter the fingerprint of assets in the pipeline that have NOT changed. You might want to do this to force remote caches to refetch all assets referenced in your HTML.

This might be useful if you have some upstream cache (like varnish) that you want to refetch all assets for some reason.

Under normal circumstances the pipeline will alter the fingerprint on each file when the contents of the files changes (even for binary files like images).

Comment: How I'm using it is pretty unique: a mobile phonegap app that loads ajax requests.  In every request I include the assets version, and reload the entire page if things are out of date.  From what you say, the correct thing to do here would simply be to tap in to the parameter that sprockets tacks as a parameter to application.js.  I'll have to look in to that.